# Crafty.js : having problems with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, craftyjs

I am using following code with Crafty. 0.5.3 (cause Crafty 0.5.4, crashed my game for unknown reasons, nvm, i'm all right with crafty0.5.3, at least now...) to make my player move by 4px for 8 times (making it whole 32px) but sloooowly, by using timeout, i want to delay by 3 milliseconds each time for loop is ...looped(?) so that i can have 24 milliseconds delay which should set with my animation.

Following is the code i am using, putMessage is function to show some message in message box which i already made, first parameter in this function is message and second is boolean value which tells whether this should be added in message box (msg += value) or should replace the msg (only msg = value)

```
    moveLeft: function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
                var d= new Date();
                putMessage(i+1 + "result : " + d.getSeconds() + "." + d.getMilliseconds() + "<br/ >", true);
                this.move('w',4);
                this.borderCheck();
                putMessage(d.getSeconds() + "." + d.getMilliseconds() + "<br>", true);
        }, 3)
    }
  },
```

Here is the result in message box, pls don't take miliseconds after 1digit in consideration.
*9result : 49.493

9result : 49.493

9result : 49.493

9result : 49.509

9result : 49.509

9result : 49.509

9result : 49.509

9result : 49.509*

see that '9', why 9 is there, because i guess, there should be values like 1result, 2result, ....8result, .... 9 shouldn't be anywhere..and second putMessage doesn't seems to work....neither player is moved.but if remove setTimeout() like,

```
moveLeft: function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        var d= new Date();
            putMessage(i+1 + "result : " + d.getSeconds() + "." + d.getMilliseconds() + "<br/ >", true);
            this.move('w',4);
            this.borderCheck();
            putMessage(d.getSeconds() + "." + d.getMilliseconds() + "<br>", true);
    }
  },
```

the result obtained in message box is,
*1result : 36.176

36.176

2result : 36.176

36.176

3result : 36.176

36.176

4result : 36.176

36.176

5result : 36.192

36.192

6result : 36.192

36.192

7result : 36.192

36.192

8result : 36.192

36.192*

see? perfect....and more importantly, player moves..!

So what does setTimeout actually does....btw, it is working fine at another place, so is it setting any limit like only first 2 lines of codes are executed or something?

Please HELP, I am yet very new to this language.

Thanks in advance :D

**EDIT** : I resolved it after adding following line just before for loop

```
intPlayer = this; //intPlayer = internalPlayer;
```

and then i changed "this.move" and "this.borderCheck()" with "intPlayer.move" and "intPlayer.borderCheck()" ...and things become great...

Can somebody explain why?

Comment: `setTimeout` is a bad way thing to use in a game engine, no matter the language. Basically games are state machines and an update is run on them regularly (at 30 FPS 30 times per second). You'll need to check for the time passed and then update the animation based on that.

Comment: @DamonGant well, i am still getting bad result errors, can you explain what you said and crafty has 50FPS so edited crafty source file, but pls explain.

Comment: I don't know crafty, but setTimeout is certainly not the right solution. It is just not accurate enough. Refer to the crafty docs or examples.

Comment: I asked that what you meant by checking for time passed...did you meant that i should check for time passed while animation? oh yeah..you probably meant that..

Answer (score 0):

To answer why the context in `setTimeout` is different:
The setTimeout function saves your callback function into a queue. When the time is right the callback function will be invoked. The problem is that the context of your callback function gets lost - it does not know **from which object** you called setTimeout, so it can't call the callback function with `this` set to the **aforementioned object**.
Taken from [MDN's setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.setTimeout#The_.22this.22_problem) documentation page.